# Saving tkinter entries to a text file

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I'm trying to get the information from the entries to be saved into a text file, this is what I have so far and the error that comes up. Also if there's a better way to write this, constructive criticism is always appreciated!

> line 16, in submit
> print(fname.get())
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fname' referenced before assignment

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time
import random
import pygame
from pygame import mixer

win = Tk()
win.config(background="light goldenrod yellow")
win.title("Register!")
win.geometry("400x600")

def submit(event):
    u = open("user.txt","r+")
    print(fname.get())
    fname = fname.get()
    sname = sname.get()
    email = email.get()
    age = age.get()
    u.write(fname + "," + sname + "," + email + "," + age + ",")



fname = Entry(win,width=30)
fname.place(x=125, y=50)

sname = Entry(win,width=30)
sname.place(x=125, y=70)

email = Entry(win,width=30)
email.place(x=125, y=90)

age = Entry(win,width=30)
age.place(x=125, y=110)


submitBtn = Button(win, text="submit")
submitBtn.place(x=180, y=140)
submitBtn.bind('<Button-1>', submit)

win.mainloop()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is what it says:

```
def submit(event):
    global fname,sname,email,age
    u = open("user_gui.txt","r+")
    print(fname.get())
    f_name = fname.get()
    s_name = sname.get()
    e_mail = email.get()
    a_ge = age.get()
    u.write(f_name + "," + s_name + "," + e_mail + "," + a_ge + ",")
```

Its better to change each variable to something else, so as to avoid confusion for python, or it will think fname is the string rather than entry widget, later on.

Comment: If I remove ```print(fname.get())``` it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @Anna Also change the variable names

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding the circular referencing by using a class:

```
import tkinter as tk


class myApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Register")
        self.geometry("400x600")
        self.config(background="light goldenrod yellow")

        self.first_name = tk.Entry(self, width = 30)
        self.first_name.place(x = 125, y = 50)
        self.first_name.insert(0, 'Optional Default Text')

        self.sur_name = tk.Entry(self, width = 30)
        self.sur_name.place(x = 125, y = 70)

        self.email = tk.Entry(self, width = 30)
        self.email.place(x = 125, y = 90)

        self.age = tk.Entry(self, width = 30)
        self.age.place(x = 125, y = 110)


        self.submit_button = tk.Button(self, text = 'submit', command = lambda: self.submit())
        self.submit_button.place(x = 180, y = 140)


    def submit(self):
        print('i am submitting')
        with open("user.txt", "a") as target_file:
            target_file.write(f"{self.first_name.get()},{self.sur_name.get()},{self.email.get()},{self.age.get()}")
            target_file.write("\n")


def main():
    app = myApp()
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- try to avoid the star * - imports, since you might run into trouble in larger projects, in case functions / classes in different modules have the same names.
- use the filehandler "with open( < file >, < mode >) as <variable_name>:" it will close the file at the end of the block for you automatically.
- i used "a" in order to append at the user.txt file. might be useful in case you want to store multiple users. in case it is just one, "w" write should do the job.